# How to connect Jmeter to Java class?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. Currently i have tested web service calls in Jmeter. I have sent a request to server through web service calls. My input is xml file and its encrypted form. So i given encrypted string in PostBody.

My problem is I'm not able to do the encryption process in Jmeter.
So i have decided to connect jmeter to my java class and send to server.

```
Jmeter--->Java class--->server.
```

I have used Jmeter 2.8

Is there any possible to connect Jmeter to java class?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to understand but if what you want to do is the following:

1. Encrypt some XML
2. Pass it as Raw Post Body to the HTTP Sampler which will call your webservice

Then the answer to do that is the following:

1. Add groovy-all.jar in JMETER_HOME/lib folder
2. Use a [JSR223 Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) on your HTTP sampler, and put the following Groovy code:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument;

   HTTPSamplerBase httpSamplerBase = (HTTPSamplerBase) sampler;

   HTTPArgument argument = 
               httpSamplerBase.getArguments().getArgument(0);

   String valueToEncrypt = argument.getValue();
   // Do you encryption here, in this example I put ENC for testing
   valueToEncrypt = "ENC"+valueToEncrypt;
   httpSamplerBase.getArguments().clear();
   httpSamplerBase.addNonEncodedArgument("", valueToEncrypt, "");
   ```
3. In the [HTTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request), put your original XML to be encrypted in Raw Post Body text area

Plan will have following structure (HTTP mirror server is just for my test):

[image]

**Note: I use current JMeter nightly build so I have Script Compilation caching part which is not yet available and will be in 2.9. Instead put your script in an external file and reference it in File Name field.**

Comment: When will JMeter 2.9 be available?

Comment: Don't know yet, should be at begining of year but if you need it, you can get nightly build and give feedback

Comment: I have written groovy script in preprocessor.How can i pass that value to http request?

Comment: It s in my script the last 3 lines

Comment: I have written script in preprocessor and executes it.while running the application there was nothing happening.I up voted your answer.

Comment: Script modifies the sampler, check in view tree result the request and also check no error in your script

Comment: Show content of your script

Answer (score 1):

jMeter can talk to a lot of things (see [this list](http://jmeter.apache.org/) at Apache). One is JMS and that could probably be used to connect to your java server. Or http (which it's normally used for). It all depends on what your java class is able to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a jar of your java class, and append it to your test plan. You can then reference them from the JSR223 preprocessor with the groovy engine. [image: Jmeter with lib added]