# jmeter dynamically sign / hash a url

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to test a restful web service which requires a custom authentication scheme (MD5 of the URL with a recent timestamp).

e.g. URL `http://test.com/secret/stuff/csv_val?uid=123&ts=1388695589&sig=e8dcf859a079e8670a5765e3eb0413e4`

Where `csv_val` is a dynamic value coming from a CSV file, `uid` is my user ID, `ts` is the current timestamp and `sig` is the MD5 of `MY_SECRET_KEYhttp://test.com/secret/stuff/csv_val?uid=123&ts=1388695589`

From my research I *think* I should be using a JSR223 pre-processor to generate the timestamp and MD5 but it is not clear how I can get access to the full URL inside the script. I found an SO post ([How to connect Jmeter to Java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056089/how-to-connect-jmeter-to-java-class)) which looked very promising but doesn't seem to work for me.

So my question is: how can I get access to the HTTP request parameters (host, port, path, protocol, etc...) inside a pre-processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [user defined variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) to store needed values. After that you construct your request the next way: [image]
where values in ${...} are user defined variables. Values for them can be created in BeanShell, BSF or RS2323 preprocessor. [Here](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) is some API to work with UDV. Here is pretty similar question [jmeter var.putobject variable use in other jdbc request, but it is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866023/jmeter-var-putobject-variable-use-in-other-jdbc-request-but-it-is-ignored). And [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is a link so  that you can read `csv_val` from CSV file.